# Detect Lion (OS X 10.7) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, osx-lion, user-agent, browser-detection

Is there a way to detect if the operating system is OS X Lion or not in Javascript?

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe because of a feature like "we detected you are using Lion, here's the correct download for your operating system - if our detection was wrong, click here to select manually"?

Comment: yeah that's a good one. but i was just detecting to see if there were hidden overlay scroll bars or normal scroll bars in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user agent of Safari (and also Firefox) in Lion is something like

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/534.48.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.48.3
```

There is "Mac OS X 10_7_1" in it - this indicates Lion (= Mac OS 10.7).

See here: http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

You can read the user agent string using "navigator.userAgent"

Comment: Just remember that if you want your code to be robust to handle future OS releases, make sure you look for versions of MacOS "newer" than 10.7.1.  That is parse the OS version string into x.y.z and check for "isLionOrLater = (x > 10) || ((x == 10) && (y >= 7));"

Answer (score 2):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
`BrowserDetect.OS` I don't know its compatibility though. <- This link does use the useragent.