# Detect Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-agent, browser-detection, osx-mountain-lion

like [Detect Lion (OS X 10.7) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706019/detect-lion-os-x-10-7-in-javascript) but I need to detect the last OS (Mountain Lion).

Can someone tell me the user agent of Safari / Firefox / chrome on this OS?

Unfortunately I don't have a mac...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the Mountain Lion User Agent string for Safari:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.25
```

So the 10_8 part of the string is the relevant factor in determining Mountain Lion. Just don't forget that as updates appear for Mountain Lion that will change to 10_8_1, etc.

EDIT:

The FireFox UA is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
```

You can see the OS portion is a little different, using 10.8 instead of 10_8.

Comment: Hi! can you get me also the firefox useragent? Just to be sure the OS part is the same...

Comment: @VitoDeTullio, I have updated the answer with the FireFox string.